# ¿Como puedo responder peticiones http localmente mediante un DNS local?

Tags: http, https, dns, localhost, http-get

Me gustaría redirigir el trafico que se genere desde una app para que descargue archivos localmente.

Es decir, la app APPMOVIL hace una consulta a SERVER.WEB/data?a=1... Pero necesito darle respuesta a esa app mediante una red local. De forma que pueda recibir la consulta y las descargas todo desde el servidor local. Así cuando reciba la respuesta JSON:

```
{
 fileUrl:"https://server.web/file.pdf"
}
```

La app pueda descargar el archivo local, pues el servidor le da respuesta cacheadas.

**SIN INTERNET. TODO LOCALMENTE**

He buscado soluciones DNS pero no logro una respuesta o solución directa.

ESQUEMA
[image: Esquema sobre peticiones locales]

Comment: `fileURL: "https://IP_DEL_SERVER/file.pdf"`, por ejemplo `https://192.168.10.11/file.pdf`

Comment: Siempre puedes editar tu archivo `host` y añadir ahí la IP y el nombre del servidor que tiene que responder. No sé en qué s.o. te mueves, pero añadiendo una línea como esta `192.168.1.159. Server.web` te podría resolver parte de tu problema

Comment: Acabo de añadir un esquema de ejemplo.

Comment: Muy bien, @Jakala pero creo que eso funcionaria solo en el servidor, no en la red completa. A menos que este usando el servidor como DNS. Que creo que es la solución más simple. Pero no lo tengo todo claro

Comment: @Trauma eso pudiera resultar solo **despues** de que ya el servidor le de una respuesta a la app. Pero **antes** debe darle una respuesta precacheada que la app solicita a un host

Comment: No. Lo del host funcionaria solo en el ordenador que lo tenga configurado. Si quieres que toda la red pueda acceder, entonces o vas a todos los ordenadores y cambias esos host, o montas un dns y que todos los ordenadores usen ese DNS como principal...

Comment: @Jakala exactamente. eso es lo que pensaba. O ponerle al enrutador la dirección del DNS local. Asi me evito cambiar todos los DNS. Pero necesito saber como montar el DNS para que me haga el trabajo asi.

Comment: O programarlo para buscar en una base de datos las respuestas a cada solicitud. programarlo

Comment: Si tienes algún ordenador para usar como servidor, podrías montar un dns. O incluso con un docker montar un server bind9. Pero en cualquier caso, todos los ordenadores tienen que cambiar su DNS principal a ese nuevo